# Unhandled exception in MVC4

Tags: exception, unhandled

I am trying to make a password reset page for a project I'm working on that will utilize SMS texting for a verification code. Right now I am just trying to get the layout right using a template that VS 2012 uses. I am trying to put in a dropdown list for people to be able to select mobile carriers from a list. I am using MVC4 for this project btw. Here is what I have for the Model:

```
public class PwResetModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Carrier")]        
    public SelectList Carrier { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have for the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Carrier)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Carrier, new SelectList(Model.Carrier))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Carrier)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

It keeps throwing an unhandled exception for the dropdownlist line.

here is the error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be appreciated.